# не получается соединиться с компьютером по ssh

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ssh

В общем надо соединиться с компьютером  по ssh . НО так и не понял что я делаю не так.

На машине к которой хочу подключиться делаю перезагрузку ssh . И запускаю ssh .

```
root@R2CPU:~# service ssh restart
root@R2CPU:~# service ssh start
root@R2CPU:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.111  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 00:1f:f2:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4066  bytes 422817 (412.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 883  bytes 37086 (36.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1589  bytes 139429 (136.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1589  bytes 139429 (136.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

На другой машине пытаюсь присоединиться :

```
comp@comp0:~$ ssh 192.168.1.111
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.111 port 22: Connection timed out
```

В общем не подключилось :(

В общем так и не понял, что я не так делаю .

В конфигурационный файл `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` не лез (всё стандартное).
Вот "он":

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
```

---

Попробовал `nmap`

```
comp@comp0:~$ nmap -p22 192.168.1.111

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-01 12:46 MSK
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.05 seconds
comp@comp0:~$ nmap 192.168.1.111

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-01 12:46 MSK
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.05 seconds
comp@comp0:~$ ssh 192.168.1.111
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.111 port 22: Connection timed out

comp@comp0:~$ nmap -Pn -p22 192.168.1.111

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-10-01 12:55 MSK
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.111
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.40 seconds
```

`ifconfig`  на клиенской машине :

```
comp@comp0:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.8.106  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.8.255
        inet6 fe80::433e:3621:7ea4:caa4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether bc:ae:c5:d8:4e:ff  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 39312  bytes 29092453 (29.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24969  bytes 4286043 (4.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Локальная петля (Loopback))
        RX packets 2598  bytes 266475 (266.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2598  bytes 266475 (266.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

Решил попробывать от атвратного , вспомнил что отвратный это я :3 и посему решил наоборот попробывать, сейчас *debian 9 сервер, Ubuntu 18 клиент*  а будет *debian 9 клиент, Ubuntu 18 сервер*

вот сервер на Убунте

```
 comp@comp0:~$ ifconfig 
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.8.106  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.8.255
        inet6 fe80::433e:3621:7ea4:caa4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether bc:ae:c5:d8:4e:ff  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 45932  bytes 41114861 (41.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34976  bytes 8223651 (8.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Локальная петля (Loopback))
        RX packets 3028  bytes 312797 (312.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3028  bytes 312797 (312.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

comp@comp0:~$ service ssh start 
comp@comp0:~$
```

А вот клиент Дебиан

```
root@R2CPU:/# service ssh stop
root@R2CPU:/# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.8.169  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.8.255
        ether 00:1f:f2:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21301  bytes 2143902 (2.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4176  bytes 180772 (176.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1368  bytes 129809 (126.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1368  bytes 129809 (126.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@R2CPU:/# ssh 172.16.8.106
The authenticity of host '172.16.8.106 (172.16.8.106)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:TxUTkjjnCo87SUjePlU/h76UnyeL/8CzG+5sd8bZa5A.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '172.16.8.106' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@172.16.8.106's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@172.16.8.106's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@172.16.8.106's password:
Permission denied (publickey,password).
root@R2CPU:/# ssh 172.16.8.106
root@172.16.8.106's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@172.16.8.106's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@172.16.8.106's password:
Permission denied (publickey,password).
root@R2CPU:/#
```

Требует какойто код , которого у меня нету :(

Пытался использовать имя и пароль от компа сервера (именно пользовательский ) но как то не вышло ((

---

В  файле   `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`  на сервере изменил строку :

```
 PermitRootLogin no
```

Но всё равно просит ввести какой-то пароль (единственный плюс он хотябы начал отвечать (именно сервер дебиан :3 )).

```
comp@comp0:/$ ssh 172.16.8.169
comp@172.16.8.169's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
comp@172.16.8.169's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
comp@172.16.8.169's password: 
comp@172.16.8.169: Permission denied (publickey,password).
comp@comp0:/$
```

При подключенини одноразовый пароль   нигде не создаётся и не выводится

**Где "добыть" этот чертов пароль ???**

Comment: `nmap -p22 192.168.1.111`

Comment: @donRumata  а что дальше делать ??

Comment: Другой компьютер в той же сети? Может на роутере файлвол настроен?

Comment: И почему вы пингуете `192.168.29.59`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen да комп присоединен через разветвитель. От от одной сети оба

Comment: Какой `ifconfig` на `comp0`? Cудя по `From 213.131.7.129` они таки в разных сетях

Comment: @AlexeyTen да,вопрос обновил.

Comment: Ну так они в разных сетях, причём `192.168.` это приватная сеть в которую снаружи роутинга нет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen не подскажите что мне надо сделать чтоб заработало через ssh (просто я сейчас вообще думаю проблема в ключе сисиашинском , я както один раз продвинулся чуть дальше написал слово yes  но меня чёт ssh не пустил )

Comment: может быть ufw блокирует соединение на сервере?

Comment: ssh тут вообще ни при чём. Разберитесь сначала с сетями.

Comment: Нарисуй схему как у тебя компы расположены и что есть ещё в локалке. Вообще не понятно что\где.

Comment: @donRumata по правде говоря я не понимаю где он создаёт , **одноразовый пароль** и почему я его не разу не увидел на экране монитора.

Comment: Эммм... одноразовый? Ты уверен, что классический линукс с классическими настройками в ссх создаёт одноразовый пароль?

Comment: Это не одноразовый пароль, это пароль пользователя от имени которого вы хотите подсоединиться. Допустим у вас на сервере (компьютер к которому подсоединяетесь) есть пользователь ivan с паролем 12345. Попробуйте сделать ssh 192.168.bla.bla -l ivan       Далее будет запрошен пароль для пользователя ivan. Вы его введете и все должно получиться.

Comment: @КонстантинРыбаков, если `nmap` говорит, что порт 22 `filtred`, то хоть по клюучу, хоть по паролю - результата не будет. Нужно, чтобы был `open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем узнал надо было создать SSH-ного пользователя на **ssh-сервере**.

сначала создаём пользователя:

```
useradd testssh
```

потом устанавливаем пароль :

```
passwd testssh
```

Производим перезагрузку ssh:

```
root@R2CPU:/# service ssh restart
```

И теперь в **клиенте** вводим :

```
ssh testssh@172.16.8.169
```

после этого просит ввести код вводим его  :3

---

По правде говоря **сервер** дал мне странный вывод но при этом всё заработало :

```
root@R2CPU:/# useradd testssh
useradd: failed to reset the faillog entry of UID 1000: Is a directory
root@R2CPU:/# passwd testssh
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
root@R2CPU:/# service ssh start
root@R2CPU:/# service ssh restart
root@R2CPU:/# service ssh start
```

---

Также замечу что  filtered на **сервере**

```
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
```

был связан с тем что надо было выполнить команду `sudo apt-get update` после её ввода :

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```